# Automatic parameter generation from Stored Procedure SSRS 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

I have a ssrs 2005 report that has a stored procedure on sql server 2005 as its datasource.

At first, the sp had no parameters, it just returned values.

The sp changed now,  a lot of parameters were added.

Now i need to add report parameters for the report, and bind them to the sp parameters

Is there a way for the report to automaticaly generate the parameters and bind them to the sp parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, When you look in the DATA tab in the RDL design, you can see the datasets that your report uses.

In there, there's a refresh icon that refresh the information from the procedure.
After the procedure has changed, you need to refresh the RDL's dataset.
Once you refresh the dataset, the parameters should be added automatically.